# How To correctly Apply the Box component spacing props?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Adding margins and spacing can be done easily.
[Material-UI](https://v4.mui.com/) gave us some shortcuts for this.
Instead of CSS styling each component.

> In the following line of code, The *margin* does not apply correctly
> without specifying the **px** measurement unit

```
 <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" marginRight={`${theme.spacing(25)}px`}>...</Box>
```

I'm trying to let MUI do the work,  and leverage the technology as opposed to using CSS classes for styling.

> However, it's more convenient to use it without string's concatenation

```
 <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" marginRight={theme.spacing(25)}>...</Box>
```

Comment: Side note, I am against the use of styling props directly on components, because once you have to heavily customize a `Box`. It can become very hard to read the structure of the components with all those props in the way. Instead, I used the `sx` props and keep all the styling in another file, just like what we used to do with HTML, CSS, and JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at docs (https://mui.com/components/box/), you should not use theme object in any way.

```
<Box display="flex" alignItems="center" marginRight={2}>...</Box>
```

Value `2` will be passed to `theme.spacing()` for you and `px` suffix will be added as well. Tested on v4.10.

PS. Not using theme means that you don't have to call `useTheme()` as well.

**EDIT**

I think I have found a possible reason of your problem. Look at this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/a0e725d119bbb91fb4f8cd6b44745916e66c2e2e/packages/mui-system/src/createTheme/createSpacing.ts#L29

If you are using mui v5, you might see message in the console (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/a0e725d119bbb91fb4f8cd6b44745916e66c2e2e/packages/mui-system/src/spacing.js#L130).

It seems that valid values passed to margin prop is from range 0-8, but you passed 25 (I never used value that high).

Please be aware that 1 does not mean 1px, the return value may vary, but it is 8px by default.

Comment: Clean and readable approach, Well tested and I approved your answer, but even `theme.spacing(value)` has an integer value! the style does not apply properly, I think he took the value and multiply it by `*` the spacing default value `8px`

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.